# awk next month last date logic issue

Tags: awk

I searched SO, but could find answers using programming languages like Java, Python, JS, etc.
I'm trying to find the next month last date when a relative date is given as input to the awk. Looking for awk implementation.

Here is my logic, but it breaks for different inputs.

```
$ export DT="2020-12-31"

$ awk -v dt=$DT ' BEGIN { gsub(/-/," ",dt); print dt;dt2=mktime(dt " 0 0 0"); 
while(c<2) { dd=strftime("%d",dt2+(i++)*86400);if(dd*1==1)c++;} ; print strftime("%F",dt2+(i-2)*86400) } '
2020 12 31
2021-01-31 # Correct
```

Below one is giving wrong answer

```
$ export DT="2020-01-01"

$ awk -v dt=$DT ' BEGIN { gsub(/-/," ",dt); print dt;dt2=mktime(dt " 0 0 0"); 
while(c<2) { dd=strftime("%d",dt2+(i++)*86400);if(dd*1==1)c++;} ; print strftime("%F",dt2+(i-2)*86400) } '
2020 01 01
2020-01-31 # Wrong - Should be 2020-02-29
```

what is wrong with the logic?. I welcome other awk solutions

In a similar way, I need to calculate prior-month start & end dates, relative month start and end date, next month's start and end date in a robust way using awk.

Below is the code for previous month end date

```
$ awk -v dt="2021-01-30" ' BEGIN { gsub(/-/," ",dt); print dt;dt2=mktime(dt " 0 0 0"); 
                dy=strftime("%d",dt2); print strftime("%F",dt2-dy*86400) } '
2021 01 30
2020-12-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abusing the GNU awk's `mktime`. Split the date to its components, add 2 months (for example 12+2=14) and subtract a day from the first day (01-1=0), so 2020-12-31 -> 2020-14-00 == 2021-01-31:

```
$ awk -v dt="2020-12-31" '
BEGIN {
    split(dt,a,/-/)                       # split to get the date components
    e=mktime(a[1] " " a[2]+2 " 0 0 0 0")  # add 2 months and subtract a day from 1st day
    print strftime("%F",e)                # output
}'
```

Output:

```
2021-01-31
```

Comment: this is great!.. kind of a hack.. works very well and I'm able to get the other things..

Comment: im now able to get rid of all epoch manipulations..

Comment: It is _hackish_ but [the documentation for `mktime`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) states: _The values of these numbers need not be within the ranges specified; for example, an hour of -1 means 1 hour before midnight._

Comment: Nice idea, much more concise then my approach! I'm probably just be being paranoid but I'm still not 100% convinced there isn't some weird DST and/or leap-second or something edge case you hit by using midnight and not using the UTC flag though so I'd use `mktime(a[1] " " a[2]+2 " 0 12 0 0",1)` for all day calculations just to be SURE you land in the middle of a day.

Comment: @EdMorton.. Epoch seconds are agnostic against DST and leap seconds.. as long as you deal with same timezones and date calculations, then epoch should work well..

Comment: @stack0114106 right but not every day is the same number of epoch seconds and the day and time that a specific number of epoch seconds lands in is affected by DST (and to a much lesser extent leap seconds) so IMHO when doing day calculations it's best to just use noon and UTC so you don't have to care about any of that no matter what you're doing with those day calculations.

Comment: I should add _leap seconds not supported_: `awk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%F %T",mktime("2017 01 01 00 00 -1"))}'` outputs `2016-12-31 23:59:59` (as expected). And that DST is always a pain in the - - and whoever uses this method should take it into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(dt,curYMD,/-/)

    if ( curYMD[2] < 12 ) {
        tgtYear = curYMD[1]
        tgtMth  = curYMD[2] + 1
    }
    else {
        tgtYear = curYMD[1] + 1
        tgtMth  = 1
    }

    begSecs = mktime(tgtYear" "tgtMth" 1 12 0 0",1)
    begDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",begSecs)

    for (day=31; mth!=tgtMth; day--) {
        endSecs = mktime(tgtYear" "tgtMth" "day" 12 0 0",1)
        mth = strftime("%m",endSecs)+0
    }
    endDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d",endSecs)

    print dt":\t" begDate, "->", endDate
}
```

```
$ awk -v dt='2020-12-31' -f tst.awk
2020-12-31:     2021-01-01 -> 2021-01-31
$ awk -v dt='2020-01-01' -f tst.awk
2020-01-01:     2020-02-01 -> 2020-02-29
$ awk -v dt='2021-01-30' -f tst.awk
2021-01-30:     2021-02-01 -> 2021-02-28
```

Best I can tell the problems in your code are:

1. Trying to use the average number of seconds in a day as the actual duration in seconds of all days to count in days instead of just counting in days, and
2. Using midnight as the time each day for mktime() as that causes problems with leap seconds and DST changes too, always use noon instead when you're just doing day calculations. It wouldn't hurt to add the UTC flag too to avoid DST concerns.

I used a loop to find the actual end day of the month because `mktime()` will try to guess at what you meant if you give it a date with too large a number of days for the given month so just see if the current month really supports 31 days and if not, decrement til it does (obvious will only go down to 28 max).

Hopefully the equivalent logic for the prior month start/end date is obvious but in case it's not, just change the first `if` statement to:

```
if ( curYMD[2] > 1 ) {
    tgtYear = curYMD[1]
    tgtMth  = curYMD[2] - 1
}
else {
    tgtYear = curYMD[1] - 1
    tgtMth  = 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to go with James answer. But here is the fix to my code, in case if someone is interested in the crude way of manipulating date using epoch calculations.
If I do pre-increment the "i" and then subtract it when printing, it gets right answer.

```
$ export DT="2020-12-31"

$ awk -v dt=$DT ' BEGIN { gsub(/-/," ",dt); print dt;dt2=mktime(dt " 0 0 0"); 
while(c<2) { dd=strftime("%d",dt2+(++i)*86400);if(dd*1==1)c++;} ; print strftime("%F",dt2+(i-1)*86400) } '
2020 12 31
2021-01-31
```

Case-2:

```
$ export DT="2020-01-01"
$ awk -v dt=$DT ' BEGIN { gsub(/-/," ",dt); print dt;dt2=mktime(dt " 0 0 0");
while(c<2) { dd=strftime("%d",dt2+(++i)*86400);if(dd*1==1)c++;} ; print strftime("%F",dt2+(i-1)*86400) } '
2020 01 01
2020-02-29
```