# awk to get last working day in all months of a year

Tags: unix, awk

I'm converting sql logic for finding the last working day in each month of a given year using awk.
Here is my code which looks correct but runs infinitely,

```
awk -v year=2020 ' function dtp(_dt) { return strftime("%F", mktime(_dt " 0 0 0")) }  function dtday(_dt) { return strftime("%a", mktime(_dt " 0 0 0")) }   function dtmon(_dt) { return strftime("%b", mktime(_dt " 0 0 0")) }
  BEGIN   { ldy=strftime("%j",mktime(year " 12 31 0 0 0" ))
    for(i=1;i<=ldy+0;i++)
    {
      df=year " "  1  "  " i 
      if(dtday(df) != "Sun" && dtday(df) != "Sat" )
      a[dtmon(df)]=dtp(df) "|" dtday(df)
    }
   
  }
  END {  for(i in a) print i,a[i] }
  '
```

I think I ended up with a convoluted way of doing it. Can this be fixed or are any other simpler awk solutions possible? I'm looking for output like below.

```
Fri 2020-01-31 :: 2020-01-31
Sat 2020-02-29 :: 2020-02-28 # 29 is sat, so 28
Tue 2020-03-31 :: 2020-03-31
Thu 2020-04-30 :: 2020-04-30
Sun 2020-05-31 :: 2020-05-29 # 31 is Sun, so 29
Tue 2020-06-30 :: 2020-06-30
Fri 2020-07-31 :: 2020-07-31
Mon 2020-08-31 :: 2020-08-31
Wed 2020-09-30 :: 2020-09-30
Sat 2020-10-31 :: 2020-10-30 # 31 is Sat, so 30th
Mon 2020-11-30 :: 2020-11-30
Thu 2020-12-31 :: 2020-12-31
```

Comment: When you say "last working day" - do you mean last week day (i.e. Mon->Fri) or would a month where the last day is Monday but that is a public holiday mean that the "last working day" is actually the preceding Friday?

Comment: yes... right, Im just working on a simple problem (Mon to Fri) and ignoring holidays for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using GNU awk for time functions, the following works because in mktime() arguments the 0th day of the next month is actually considered the last day of the current month, -1th day of next month is the 2nd-last day of the current month, the 13th month of this year is considered the 1st month of next year, etc. so invalid dates like `2021 13 -1` or the equivalent `2022 1 -1` are treated by mktime() like the valid date `2021 12 30`.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    oneDaySecs = 24 * 60 * 60
    weekEndSecs["Sat"] = oneDaySecs
    weekEndSecs["Sun"] = 2 * oneDaySecs
    for (mthNr=2; mthNr<=13; mthNr++) {
        lastDaySecs = mktime(year " " mthNr " " "0 12 0 0",1)
        lastDayName = strftime("%a",lastDaySecs)
        weekDaySecs = lastDaySecs - weekEndSecs[lastDayName]
        print lastDayName, strftime("%F",lastDaySecs), "::", strftime("%F",weekDaySecs)
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -v year=2020 -f tst.awk file
Fri 2020-01-31 :: 2020-01-31
Sat 2020-02-29 :: 2020-02-28
Tue 2020-03-31 :: 2020-03-31
Thu 2020-04-30 :: 2020-04-30
Sun 2020-05-31 :: 2020-05-29
Tue 2020-06-30 :: 2020-06-30
Fri 2020-07-31 :: 2020-07-31
Mon 2020-08-31 :: 2020-08-31
Wed 2020-09-30 :: 2020-09-30
Sat 2020-10-31 :: 2020-10-30
Mon 2020-11-30 :: 2020-11-30
Thu 2020-12-31 :: 2020-12-31
```

See also [awk next month last date logic issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68749062/1745001) for other day-of-month calculations.

Comment: this is nice.. reducing to only 12 iterations.